# Can't get 2 Dynamic Paint Canvases to render at once - Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, shaders, vertex-groups, vertex-colors, dynamic-paint

Trying to render both the waves and trail of a boat using 2 dynamic paint canvases, one of the Waves Surface Type, and one of the Paint Surface Type. The two show up together perfectly in the viewport, but for some reason when rendered out, only one of the Bakes appears. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Blender file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ifVx50dHrmQLoipd2KTRkFLt6xYGBwNB

Viewport:

[image]

Render:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually name the cache in order both canvas layers to render.

[image]